# Verilog Error: Can't elaborate user hierarchy "counter:counter"

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I'm tring to write snake from LED on a Quartus Board. It's kind of like KITT-Leds, but when I try to run my program, I get an error.

```
module ukol3(KEY,LEDR);
input[1:0]KEY;
output[14:0] LEDR;

counter counter(KEY[0], KEY[1], LEDR[14:0]);

endmodule

module counter(C,CLR,Q);
input C, CLR;
output [14:0] Q;
reg [14:0] tmp;
integer i;

always @(posedge C or posedge CLR)      
    begin

        if (CLR)
            tmp = 15'b000000000000000;

        if (tmp == 15'b111111111111111)
            i = 0;

        if (tmp == 15'b000000000000000)
            i = 1;

        if (i == 1)
            tmp = tmp + 1'b1;

        if (i == 0)
            tmp = tmp - 1'b1;
        end 
    assign Q = tmp;


endmodule
```

This gives me an error:

> Error: Can't elaborate user hierarchy "counter:counter"

I really don't know what's going on.

Comment: I think the error message is telling you that always block is not synthesizable. Consider using non-blocking assignments for inferring registers.

Comment: Give the instance a different name than the module.  Your code is a good copy of the data on pastebin, but what is snake supposed to do?  Is it actually a shift register that should fill and then empty?  The integer i will only change state on a rising edge of clock that catches the counter at its maximum or minimum count.  Otherwise it will latch the most recent setting. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is about Verilog, not vhdl. I want to ask a couple of questions: Is your code synthesizable? and what do you get after a synthesis module counter?

For your question, I think you should compile `counter` first, then compile `ukol3`. The EDA tool will not find counter when you didn't did it first. You should split it into two separable files and do the counter first.

P.S.: You should use a better mapping port method such as `counter counter (.C(KEY[0]),.CLR (KEY[1]),.Q (LEDR[14:0]));` for clearer code.